# Magento 2: import special price for configurable products from M1

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, importexport, special-price

In Magento 1 the special prices were added to configurable products. In Magento 2 the special prices are set for simple products associated with the main configurable product.

Is there an easy way to export special prices from M1 shop's configurable products and then import the special prices for the correct simple products?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem upgrading from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4. Did you find a solution?